# Accuracy of resnet model for sign language recognition not increasing

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-science

Here is the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/grassknoted/asl-alphabet

```
    def res_block(X, filter, stage):
    
      # Convolutional_block
      X_copy = X
    
      f1 , f2, f3 = filter
    
      # Main Path
      X = Conv2D(f1, (1,1),strides = (1,1), name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_conv_a', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same')(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_conv_a')(X)
      X = Activation('relu')(X) 
    
      X = Conv2D(f2, kernel_size = (3,3), strides =(1,1), padding = 'same', name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_conv_b', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_conv_b')(X)
      X = Activation('relu')(X) 
    
      X = Conv2D(f3, kernel_size = (1,1), strides =(1,1),name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_conv_c', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_conv_c')(X)
    
    
      # Short path
      X_copy = Conv2D(f3, kernel_size = (1,1), strides =(1,1),name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_conv_copy', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X_copy)
      X_copy = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same')(X_copy)
      X_copy = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_conv_copy')(X_copy)
    
      # ADD
      X = Add()([X,X_copy])
      X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
      # Identity Block 1
      X_copy = X
    
    
      # Main Path
      X = Conv2D(f1, (1,1),strides = (1,1), name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_identity_1_a', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_identity_1_a')(X)
      X = Activation('relu')(X) 
    
      X = Conv2D(f2, kernel_size = (3,3), strides =(1,1), padding = 'same', name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_identity_1_b', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_identity_1_b')(X)
      X = Activation('relu')(X) 
    
      X = Conv2D(f3, kernel_size = (1,1), strides =(1,1),name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_identity_1_c', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_identity_1_c')(X)
    
      # ADD
      X = Add()([X,X_copy])
      X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
      # Identity Block 2
      X_copy = X
    
    
      # Main Path
      X = Conv2D(f1, (1,1),strides = (1,1), name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_identity_2_a', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_identity_2_a')(X)
      X = Activation('relu')(X) 
    
      X = Conv2D(f2, kernel_size = (3,3), strides =(1,1), padding = 'same', name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_identity_2_b', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_identity_2_b')(X)
      X = Activation('relu')(X) 
    
      X = Conv2D(f3, kernel_size = (1,1), strides =(1,1),name ='res_'+str(stage)+'_identity_2_c', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
      X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_'+str(stage)+'_identity_2_c')(X)
    
      # ADD
      X = Add()([X,X_copy])
      X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
      return X

    
input_shape = (64, 64, 3)

X_input = Input(input_shape)

# Zero-padding
X = ZeroPadding2D((3,3))(X_input)

# 1 - stage
X = Conv2D(64, (7,7), strides= (2,2), name = 'conv1', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_conv1')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)
X = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides= (2,2), padding='same')(X)

# 2 - stage
X = res_block(X, filter= [64,64,256], stage= 2)

# 3 - stage
X = res_block(X, filter= [128,128,512], stage= 3)

# 4 - stage
X = res_block(X, filter= [256,256,1024], stage= 4)

# 5 - stage
X = res_block(X, filter= [512,512,2048], stage= 5)


# Average Pooling
X = AveragePooling2D((2,2), name = 'Averagea_Pooling', padding='same')(X)

# Final layer
X = Flatten()(X)
X = Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(X)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = Dense(2048, activation = 'relu')(X)
X = Dropout(0.1)(X)
X = Dense(29, activation = 'relu')(X)


my_model = Model( inputs= X_input, outputs = X)
my_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
my_model.summary()

history = my_model.fit(train_gen, epochs=10, validation_data=val_gen)
```

Can anyone tell how technique to increase accuracy for this code, after sometime, loss gets to nan.will applying callbacks like earlystopping or modelcheckpoint help in increasing accuracy.
for the 1st epoch, loss: 8.6760 - accuracy: 0.0637 - val_loss: 7.9905 - val_accuracy: 0.1003
and for 2nd epoch loss becomes nan

Comment: Loss becomes Nan when your data contains NaN values. Check your data properly before feeding to the model

Comment: there are no nan values

Comment: One of the cause for Accuracy not increasing can be fault in dataset. You can make a small dataframe using `iloc` and use this model in that small dataframe. If the accuracy is still not increasing then we can look into code

Comment: use iloc in image dataset?

Comment: Your last layer should include `softmax` instead of `relu`.

Comment: how to retrieve accuracy from checkpoint callback?